# change methods vuejs to nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to transform this method. I have this vue.js code:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('user/auth', ['Id']),
},
async mounted() {
  await this.doFetchCustomer(this.Id)
},

methods: {
  async doFetchCustomer(Id) {
    const app = { $axios: this.$axios }
    const datas = (await customerApi.getData(app, Id)) || []
    console.log(datas)
  },
},
```

I want to transform this code to nuxt `asyncData` but what I have tried below isn't working. How can I transform it properly?

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('user/auth', ['Id'])
},
async asyncData({$axios}) {
  const datas = (await customerApi.getData($axios, this.Id )) || [];
  console.log(datas);
  return {datas}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue so far? You could not use it the same way in `mounted()` or in the `fetch()` hook?

Comment: the issue  I would like to use the asyncData hook to retrieve the data without going through the mounted or a method as is the case

Comment: No, what I mean is: where is the bug here? What is wrong on your side? Also, your `mapGetters` is taking `Id`, while your `getData` function is using `this.id`? Sure this is not an issue here? Do you see `datas` in your `console.log`?

Comment: I'm sorry I just fixed the Id when I use the asyncdata hook the function is not called that is my issue

Comment: Alright, how do you move to the related page? It is not called at all? Can you please show us the component that do have the `asyncData` by editing your question and the one that is triggering the navigation.

Comment: I want to use asyncData hook but is not work

Comment: Please answer to my previous comment. I did get that this is not working. But we need more details to move forward here.

Comment: I tried to make my question clearer the asyncData function is not called

Comment: Can you please answer this one? "Alright, how do you move to the related page? It is not called at all? Can you please show us the component that do have the `asyncData` by editing your question and the one that is triggering the navigation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `asyncData` isn't called in your component suggests that the component is not a page component.

The [Nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching) state the requirement:

> The `asyncData` hook. This hook can only be placed on *page* components.

You can switch to the [`fetch` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook) instead, which would work for all component types:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      datas: null
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    this.datas = (await customerApi.getData(this.$axios, this.Id)) || [];
  },
}
```